# How do it test this Javascript with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, json, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a problem I want to test this javascript

```
$("#ShootBtn").on('click', () => foo.testFunc());

var foo = {
    testFunc: function() {
        hub.server.shoot(true, username, gameCode);
   }
}
```

I'm using Jasmine as my test framework, and I have tried Karma and Chutzpah as my test runner.

In my test project where I try to refer to the file above I try have tried a lot of different things, but I can't seem to get my head around it. The test looks like this atm.

```
/// <reference path="../../TankWebApplication/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../TankWebApplication/Scripts/virtualjoystick.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../TankWebApplication/Scripts/gameController.js"/>


describe("DefaultTest",
function () {

    beforeEach(function() {

    })

    it("Test",
        function() {
            spyOn(foo, 'testFunc');
            document.getElementById('ShootBtn').click();
            expect(foo.testFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();

        });


});
```

The testFunc haven't been called says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

Which I think means that it cannot click on my shootBtn

Is it impossible to test this, or what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to spy on `document.getElementById` and make it return an object that has `click` function :

```
   spyOn(document, "getElementById").andCallFake(() => ({
       click: () => foo.testFunc()
   }));
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xch52add/)

Otherwise, create an element with id = `ShootBtn`, attach a click handler to it then add it to the body (all this should be done inside your test)

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vj9z04o/)

Comment: Thank you :) Does this mean that it is not possible to trigger the button event handler from the Javascript, and that way test that it calls the right function?

Comment: Check my second example

Comment: In that example don't you add a new event listener instead of using the one that is already made in the in my original file?

Comment: You can do that [too](https://jsfiddle.net/o0yyek29/), I just didn't see the need of using jQuery